# Color on mouseover in FF Developer Plugin

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a functionality similar to Photoshop where I can mouseover the element and see colors used in it?

I know of a Information -> View Color Information tool, but it doesn't achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [ColorZilla extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/colorzilla/) which seems close to what you ask for.